# Fill in a text field after clicking a button

Tags: javascript

I have a form in php/html that is being used to enter a user's login.  I have a text field for the password that I want the user to fill in a value or click a button to get a random value entered into that field.

I found some JavaScript online but I can't make it work for my application. I don't know JavaScript that well as you can see in the code I'm using below.

```
<script>
    function getRndInteger(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }
</script>

Password 1:  <input type="text" size="20" name="PW1" value="$PW1" required>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('PW1').innerHTML = getRndInteger(10000,99999)">Assign Random Password</button>
```

Comment: ...all it takes for one to eventually break into a lazy user's account is to "guess" a username and try a linear table of integers from *10000* to *99999* and all from getting clues from your JavaScript code. Please use a better pseudorandom password generator.

Comment: Thanks Roku, point well taken.  I greatly simplified my example so it isn't this easy to get into.  But you have a good point and I will give significant thought to make sure it is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign the Id to the input text as well as to set the value and not the innerHTML.

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```html
Password 1: <input type="text" size="20" name="PW1" id="PW1" value="$PW1" required>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('PW1').value = getRndInteger(10000,99999)">Assign Random Password</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="PW1" size="20" name="PW1" value="$PW1" required>
    <button onclick="getRndInteger(10000,99999)">Assign Random Password</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  var myRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  document.getElementById('PW1').value = myRandomNumber;
}
```

Comment: PS: `getRndInteger()` function should not be called that way. Because it does not what is says. It should be called `genRandInegerAndFillItIntoPW1AsValue()`. Please learn to use separation of concerns, reusable functions, `return`, and last but not least `addEventListener`...

Comment: When I run this code the moment I click the button it submits the form.  I'm not done with the form though.  Is there a way to stay on the form?

Comment: @StevieD yes. A button by default is `type="submit"`. Simply add `type="button"` to your button